# texture coordinate precision

Tags: opengl

I am calculating uv coordinates for a bitmap font texture.
Texture size is 1024 x 1024. The uv coords are calculated on a pixel
position base. Here is the code.

```
  uv_run   = ( int8_t* )&bfs->uv[ bfs->st_ch_ind << 2 ];
  t_c_size = sizeof( t_c ); 
  x_pos    = x_st_pix;
  y_pos    = y_pix_delta * ( bfs->col_numb - 1 ) + 28;    // !!! this delta 28 has been added to center the chars

  for( c1 = 0; c1 < bfs->col_numb; c1++ )
  {
    /***********************/
    /*   process one row   */
    /***********************/
    for( c2 = 0; c2 < bfs->row_numb; c2++ )
    {
         /*******************************************/      
         /*   position in texture = x_pos / y_pos   */
         /*   this is lower left corner -> uv[ 0    */
         /*******************************************/    
         t_c[ 0 ].u = x_pos * uv_pix_fkt;
         t_c[ 0 ].v = y_pos * uv_pix_fkt;


         /*******************************************/      
         /*   go to lower right corner -> uv[ 1 ]   */
         /*******************************************/    
         x_pos += x_pix_delta;
         t_c[ 1 ].u = x_pos * uv_pix_fkt;
         t_c[ 1 ].v = y_pos * uv_pix_fkt;

         /*******************************************/      
         /*   go to upper right corner -> uv[ 2 ]   */
         /*******************************************/    
         y_pos += y_pix_delta;
         t_c[ 2 ].u = x_pos * uv_pix_fkt;
         t_c[ 2 ].v = y_pos * uv_pix_fkt;

         /*******************************************/      
         /*   go to upper left corner -> uv[ 3 ]   */
         /*******************************************/    
         x_pos -= x_pix_delta;
         t_c[ 3 ].u = x_pos * uv_pix_fkt;
         t_c[ 3 ].v = y_pos * uv_pix_fkt;

         y_pos -= y_pix_delta;
         x_pos += x_pix_delta; 
         memcpy( uv_run, t_c, t_c_size );
         uv_run += t_c_size;            
    }

    x_pos = x_st_pix;
    y_pos -= y_pix_delta;
```

This calculation does not hit the exact ( thought to be ) destination.
I have an offset in the y direction of about 28 pixels!!!
The source data comes from a DDS compressed file that has been created with compressonator.
I thought it is possible to hit every pixel on a texture with uv coos?

Comment: What's the `+ 28` for? Are you still off by 28 if you eliminate it?

Comment: without the +28 i should hit the right squares, but don't. In areas where the chars are close in y direction i can see fragments of the char in the row below. With the 28 offset i am close to the squares i wanted to be.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the texture data is correct? Are you sure there's no offset in the image itself? Do the contents render pixel-perfect (and not stretched) otherwise?

Comment: i found it - the bitmap area was alligned to the top left of the image, but the uvs  start at bottom left. The sqare with the glyphs was moved 24 pixels upwards - thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah, OpenGL uses graph paper coordinates for everything — origin in the lower left, y going upward and x going rightward. It's a common gotcha since the entire rest of the world seems to have gone with raster order.